# ASP.NET's HttpPost attributed function doesn't seem to execute after form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Good evening,
I'm quite new to ASP.NET and I'm doing my best to learn - but I've stumbled upon an issue I can't resolve - because there's no error.

I have this controller:

```
public class DatabaseFileController : Controller
{
    public static string FilePath;

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Select(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("File Reached");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And it's meant to execute when I upload a file using this form:

```
<form id="database-select-form" asp-controller="DatabaseFile" asp-action="Select" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="database-select" type="file" name="files"/>
```

I also have a script written in javascript taken from my previous website that makes form submit after file selection (and it does submit) - but nothing shows in my console or the visual studios debug console.

Edit:
As requested, added script that does the submission:

```
<script>
function select()
{
    document.getElementById('database-select').click();
    console.log("Clicked");
}

document.getElementById("database-select").onchange = function()
{
    document.getElementById("database-select-form").submit();
    console.log("Submitted");
};
```

Comment: There is no `Index` action in the shown code. what is it suppose to redirect to?

Comment: There was Index previously, the point is the function isn't called at all.

Comment: @JCode, may be it's not finding the method because name and parameters should match. Try changing parameter type to `HttpPostedFileBase file`

Comment: @derloopkat I think it would actually pop something in console if that was the case.

Comment: @JCode System.Web

Comment: Adding 'using System.Web' still doesn't find it and my references window is empty.

Comment: What shows up in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing - the console where usually javascript's console.log() printout is - is empty, aswell as the visual studio 'output' tab and the console that opens after I compile shows no errors (and it usually shows red errors when there's something wrong).

Here's output from that one console: https://pastebin.com/5FebdDZi

Comment: If the browser console was open before you tried the submit then probably it didn't do the submit.  Check the networks tab and see what requests have been sent.  This feels like something in your javascript from the previous website isn't work as you think it should.

Comment: The script works, because I can see the 'loading wheel' going, aswell as the previous console printout disappers, here's the script:

https://pastebin.com/ndzNg0us

Comment: Please update the question by adding the full html for the form and put the script there as well.

Comment: Side note, how big are the files you are trying to post?

Comment: @nurdyguy the files are about 16 to 24kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how easy this process is:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(string SubmitButton, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (SubmitButton == "Cancel")
        {
            //redirect to a cancel page
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //put a breakpoint in this metho to interogate file, 
        //the file you are going to save to db or do something with

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Tut115()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View Named Tut115.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut115</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload",
        "Home",
        FormMethod.Post,
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Cancel" />
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Upload" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2 questions then - would it work if I used IActionResult instead of ActionResult and would it work if I used regular form instead of the one generated by C# in cshtml? (form after @using (Html.Begin [...])

Comment: Yes you can use `IActionResult` and yes you can use your own form, assuming you set it up correctly.